# Order a list of dictionaries based on another dictionary

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dictionary like this, to stablish the order of the months:

```
meses_ord = {'January':1, 'February': 2, 'March':3, ... }
```

And I also have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
fechas_ = [{'anyo': 2010, 'horas': Decimal('52.5'), 'month': 'March', 'importe': Decimal('4200.000')},
{'anyo': 2010, 'horas': Decimal('40.0'), 'month': 'February', 'importe':Decimal('3200.000')},
{'anyo': 2010, 'horas': Decimal('42.5'), 'month': 'April', 'importe': Decimal('3400.000')},
{'anyo': 2010, 'horas': Decimal('20.0'), 'month': 'January', 'importe': Decimal('1600.000')}]
```

I want to order the list of dictionaries based on the month key.

I have tried many things, but none has worked:

```
fechas_ord = sorted(fechas_, key=operator.itemgetter(meses_ord[fechas_['mes']]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sort key function to look up the month:

```
def sort_by_month(entry):
    return meses_ord[entry['month']]

sorted(fechas_, key=sort_by_month)
```

The sort function can be expressed as a lambda too, just make sure it takes an argument:

```
sorted(fechas_, key=lambda entry: meses_ord[entry['month']])
```

Demo:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> meses_ord = {'January': 1, 'February': 2, 'March': 3, 'April': 4}
>>> fechas_ = [{'anyo': 2010, 'horas': Decimal('52.5'), 'month': 'March', 'importe': Decimal('4200.000')},
... {'anyo': 2010, 'horas': Decimal('40.0'), 'month': 'February', 'importe':Decimal('3200.000')},
... {'anyo': 2010, 'horas': Decimal('42.5'), 'month': 'April', 'importe': Decimal('3400.000')},
... {'anyo': 2010, 'horas': Decimal('20.0'), 'month': 'January', 'importe': Decimal('1600.000')}]
>>> pprint(sorted(fechas_, key=lambda entry: meses_ord[entry['month']]))
[{'anyo': 2010,
  'horas': Decimal('20.0'),
  'importe': Decimal('1600.000'),
  'month': 'January'},
 {'anyo': 2010,
  'horas': Decimal('40.0'),
  'importe': Decimal('3200.000'),
  'month': 'February'},
 {'anyo': 2010,
  'horas': Decimal('52.5'),
  'importe': Decimal('4200.000'),
  'month': 'March'},
 {'anyo': 2010,
  'horas': Decimal('42.5'),
  'importe': Decimal('3400.000'),
  'month': 'April'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have defined your variables as follows

```
months = {'January':1, 'February': 2, 'March':3, 'April':4 }
stuff = [{'anyo': 2010, 'horas': Decimal('52.5'), 'month': 'March', 'importe': Decimal('4200.000')},
{'anyo': 2010, 'horas': Decimal('40.0'), 'month': 'February', 'importe':Decimal('3200.000')},
{'anyo': 2010, 'horas': Decimal('42.5'), 'month': 'April', 'importe': Decimal('3400.000')},
{'anyo': 2010, 'horas': Decimal('20.0'), 'month': 'January', 'importe': Decimal('1600.000')}]
```

Then running the following will return a sorted list

```
sorted(stuff, key=lambda stuffa: months[stuffa['month']])
```

You can find out more here at the [Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) and [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)